# Why is BundleContext null when running a Java Test?

Tags: java, service, osgi, osgi-bundle

I wrote a test where I run a class that needs to load an osgi service.
When I start the Test, I get a NullPointerException everytime.
When running the application it works fine.
My Bundle Context is null. how can I solve the problem?
This is the line of the class which should load the service:

```
BundleContext ctx = getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
deviceCfgModel = getService(ctx, IDeviceCfgModel.class);
```

[A Bundle for the specified bundle class or null if the specified class was not defined by a          bundle class loader.](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/FrameworkUtil.html#getBundle%28java.lang.Class%29)

I found that explanation in the `FrameworkUtil` API but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: More context? How do you expect people to help you when it is not clear what your environment looks like?

Comment: I guess you wrote a simple JUnit test that had nothing to do with any OSGi container. You should find a way running your tests in the way that an OSGi container is started and your bundle is loaded by the container.

Answer (score 4):

`FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Class)` only works when the class was loaded by an OSGi bundle classloaders, i.e. when you are running an OSGi Framework.

Probably your JUnit tests are running in a plain JVM with no OSGi Framework. Therefore there is no BundleContext available.

If you need to test your bundle's interaction with OSGi then you need to actually run the tests inside OSGi! Otherwise, isolate your business code from the OSGi-specific glue code and then test the business code in a plain JUnit environment. A good way to achieve this isolation is to use Declarative Services.

Answer (score -2):

I have resolved the problem, when I start my Test as SWTBotTest.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Normally on StackOverflow you accept the answer that helped you solve the problem, rather than answering your own question with "I solved it"...